# Nginx location search-terminating match with regexp

Tags: http, nginx, ddos

I'm trying to set a different limit_req zone for static content.

```
location ^~ /img {
  limit_req zone=static burst=60 nodelay;
}
location ^~ /logos {
  limit_req zone=static burst=60 nodelay;
}
location ^~ /js {
  limit_req zone=static burst=60 nodelay;
}
location ^~ /plugin {
  limit_req zone=static burst=60 nodelay;
}

location / {
  limit_req zone=protected burst=5 nodelay;
}
```

This is working fine, but I want to compress those locations into one regular expression:

```
location ^~ /(img|logos|js|plugin) {
  limit_req zone=static burst=60 nodelay;
}
```

Tried this, but it is not working. Only works with ~ without ^, which will then match the location /, setting the zone back to `protected`. Is ^~ only working with literals? Any other way to achieve this in a clean way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

The following location is defined before the one with the proxy_pass and it matches the request of js and css files under static. This location block is used for different extensions you want to allow in your site.

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    limit_req zone=static burst=60 nodelay;
    log_not_found off;
  }
```

Or, you can use this I think this should work fine

```
location ~ ^/(img|logos|js|plugin)/ {
  root /project_root_path;
  limit_req zone=static burst=60 nodelay;
}
```